# How to align a table which is inside another table?

Tags: html, css

greetings all
i have a table which is inside a row of another table
and i want to control the alignment of this table to make it centre or right
how to do so ? 
(i tried the align attribute, and it didn't work)
here's a sample:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table> <!-- i want to control the alignment of this table -->
        <tbody><tr>
          <td>TD1</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD2</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would think something like

```
<table>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align:right">
      <table> <!-- i want to control the alignment of this table -->
        <tbody><tr>
          <td>TD1</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD2</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Also, make sure the width of the cell that your nested table is going into has some free space so that the nested table can move around. I.e. set width of the td and the nested table.

Comment: The text-align attribute will not change the position of the table. It only influences inline content.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<div align="center">
```

or

```
<center>

  your table 

</center>
```

Comment: The center element and align attribute are deprecated. Don't use them.